# What is the way to debug code generated by WebPack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, webpack, google-chrome-extension

This might be a very naive question but I will ask it anyway. I come from a background where I would write Chrome Extensions without Typescript and Webpack. It works very well because I could see my exact code as background scripts and content scripts and hence it was very easy to debug no matter how complex the communication between different contexts is.

Now recently, I am seeing more and more projects using Typescript and Webpack for writing chrome extensions. While debugging those, I get into a problem where the code looks very much different than the original code (of course!) and hence, it is very difficult to actually debug any messaging happening between the contexts. The source maps are already enabled and I can open a file by name in the DevTools but nonetheless code looks like a soup of `switch` statements and some weird looking `__generator` and `__awaiter` functions. My question is, how do you guys debug such applications without going crazy? There must be a way otherwise people wouldn't be jumping on the bandwagon of WebPack.

Here is an example:

Snippet of original code:

```
  static async getSearchResultsForSavedList(): Promise<Array<ParsedUser>> {
    const source = await waitForPageSource('[class="profile-card-col"]');

    let domProfiles = $(source).find('[class="profile-card-col"]');

    if (!domProfiles?.length) {
      return [];
    }

    const defaultPhoto = browserAPI.getURL('images/user.png');
...
```

Code I see in DevTools:

```
RecruiterParser.getSearchResultsForSavedList = function () {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
            var source, domProfiles, defaultPhoto;
            var _this = this;
            return __generator(this, function (_a) {
                switch (_a.label) {
                    case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, waitForPageSource('[class="profile-card-col"]')];
                    case 1:
                        source = _a.sent();
                        domProfiles = $(source).find('[class="profile-card-col"]');
                        if (!(domProfiles === null || domProfiles === void 0 ? void 0 : domProfiles.length)) {
                            return [2 /*return*/, []];
                        }
...
```

Comment: If you have the source code you should enable source maps by adding `devtool: 'inline-source-map'`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so what helped me to get rid of all those weird `switch` statements and odd-looking functions was to change `target` in `tsconfig.json` to `es6` (or higher).

It was set to `es5` and hence TS compiler was compiling it into odd-looking javascript.

Comment: You should use browserslist to set the minimum version of Chrome/Firefox to something like 100 for ManifestV3 or even higher if you use the new API that appeared just recently. It will retain all the modern JS syntax like `?.`, `??`, `...` and so on.